# Pointer to a structure in an array of structures

Tags: c++

So i need to get code of the structure#1 (e[0]) but i get the following error;
"error: request for member 'get_code' in 'emp1', which is of pointer type 'Employee*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)"
i don't really understand how to fix this. Plus, it's an assigment so i'm bound to use structures,and also, i don't know what "->" is, but if it's any operator or something, im not allowed to use it cause we haven't been taught that yet.
(Answers to the *similar* question suggest using -> so that doesnt work for me.)
i also tried using *(emp1).get_code()

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
    struct Employee{

private:
    string code;
    string name;
    float  salary;

public:
    void set_code(string c){
      code=c;
    }
    void set_name(string n){
      name=n;
    }
    void set_sal(float s){
      salary=s;
    }
    string get_code(){
      return code;
    }
    string get_name(){
      return name;
    }
    float get_sal(){
      return salary;
    }
};

int main(void) {
  Employee e[2],*emp1,*emp2;
  string c,n;
  float s;
  for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
  cout<<"Enter code for employee "<<i+1;
  cin>>c;
  e[i].set_code(c);
  cout<<"Enter name for employee "<<i+1;

  cin>>n;
  e[i].set_name(n);
  cout<<"Enter salary for employee "<<i+1;
  cin>>s;
  e[i].set_sal(s);
  }
  *emp1=e[0];
  cout<<emp1.get_code();

}
```

Comment: What's unclear about that error message?

Comment: The error is telling you to use `emp1->get_code()`. `x->y()` is generally equivalent to to `(*x).y()`.

Comment: _"i also tried using `*(emp1).get_code()`"_ Very close!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this line is not correct:

```
*emp1=e[0];
```

What your line does is assign the structure value 'e[0]' to the structure at pointer 'emp1'. However, the pointer 'emp1' is never initialized, so you'd end up writing in an invalid location.
What you need to write is:

```
emp1=&e[0];
```

That will actually set emp1 to the location of 'e[0]'.

Secondly, the symbol '->' is what you use when you want to access a member of a pointer.
In this case you should not write:

```
cout<<emp1.get_code();
```

But rather:

```
cout<<emp1->get_code();
```

The reason why you need to write that is that 'emp1' is a pointer. Thus, to access its member 'get_code', you need to use the symbol '->'.

Comment: This answer is insufficient. The line `*emp1=e[0];` above is referencing an uninitialized pointer and copying to it.

Comment: True. My bad! I'll slightly amend the comment.